# Get a list of attribute values of all elements with specific class using Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium, I'd like to get a list of *title* attributes on all elements of a specific class. I tried this code:

```cs
var link = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("class")).GetAttribute("title");
```

However, I always get only the *first element's* title.

Any ideas on how I can do it? I've thought of doing it with `foreach` loop, but I can't think of a condition that'll work...

Comment: `FindElement` implies in a name a *singular* element, not a collection... is there perhaps a `FindElements`?

Comment: FindElements exist but I can't use ".GetAttribute("title")" with it.

Comment: Right - "title" of *what*? It's a collection! You'd have to loop through the elements!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? A list of elements of this class? A list of titles of these elements? What is the relevance of `MessageBox.Show(unm)` in your post? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry, unm=link.
title is the name of the attribute each element with the class "class" has. I want to extract the value of title from each of those elements.

Comment: I am trying to achieve a list with the value of the title attribute of every element with that specific class.

Comment: I edited your question to reflect that. Please try to be clear in future posts - it'll help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need to fetch the value of "title" attribute from all elements with class name "Class". You can use FindElements method of WebDriver to get all elements with class name of "Class". From the list of all elements you can retrieve the attribute (title) value. I have also added a where clause to get rid of all the elements which has a class name of "Class" and has a empty "title" attribute.

```
    var alltitles = webDriver
            .FindElements(By.ClassName("Class"))
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.GetAttribute("title")))
            .Select(x => x.GetAttribute("title"))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Called the 4th title and "Index was out of range", therefore it's probably not working.

Comment: I got 0 and noticed I had a lil mistake, in the end it worked.
Thanks!